# Zend Action View Helper versus ActionStack Action Helper

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

I understand that the ZF ActionStack Action Helper incurs a performance hit because it retriggers the entire dispatch process.  But what about the Action View Helper?  Should I be avoiding it for the same reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the `$this->action()` view helper, then yes, avoid it for the same reason. All this does is call the action stack.